# I want to show a specific AR marker on a specified location(latitude,longitude)

Tags: flutter, geospatial, arkit, arcore

I am using arcore_flutter_plugin: ^0.1.0 , flutter to develop the application. I am able to display basic 3d shapes on my screen but I am not able to display the marker fixed to a geolocation(lat,long). I am unable to find any method or library which can help me with this. One way can be to implement it through native app. But is there any way to avoid this? I want to use Flutter to build the entire application.

I am able to display basic 3d shapes on my screen but I am not able to display the marker fixed to a geolocation(lat,long)